# Install pg gem without installing postgres macOS

Tags: macos, postgresql, docker, rubygems

This is an easy problem that can be fixed if you don't mind install Postgres database using Homebrew.

But my use case, Postgres database is run by docker in the development machine and exposing port into into host. Then I need to install gem pg to development machine which require `pg_config`. As you may know, this is operation will fail since it's not presented.

This is a bit frustrating since the quick fix is that I just have to install Postgres via Homebrew first then `gem install pg` to solve this.

But it could be better if postgres isn't required for the installation, since I already have it via docker and install it seems to be a bit of duplication.

What I would like to ask is that do we have an alternatives way for this to work without the need to install postgres ?

I'd searched about `libpq`, which available in linux but it seems it's not available for macOS.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point... You can link the folder containing the pg_config to your host who runs docker. [See the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) for the volumes or specify your question so that we can help you more ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the answer from my colleague. Install `libpq` then install `pg` gem with this command

`gem install pg -v '0.20.0' -- --with-opt-dir="/usr/local/opt/libpq"`

solve the issue

Comment: here is full explanation: https://michaelrigart.be/install-pg-ruby-gem-without-postgresql/